# Load time dropdown in php /mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a php page that allowes users to add new stock to a warehouse. On the page the user can select a location (+/- 900 records), the product (+/- 700 records), the connected purchase order (1500+/- records) and the customer order (+/- 3000 records). All records are loaded in the same way in a select function (example for locations):

```
<select data-live-search='true' required  class='selectpicker form-control border' name='wa_ra_id' value="<?php echo isset($_POST['wa_ra_id']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['wa_ra_id'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>">
      <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" value="">Select rack...</option>
                <?php

                    $database = new Database();
                    $db = $database->getConnection();

                            $query = "SELECT
                               ra_id,
                               ra_number,
                               ra_section,
                               ra_zone
                            FROM racks
                            ORDER BY ra_number";

                            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                            $stmt->execute();

                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                    extract($row);
                                    echo "<option value='{$ra_id}'>{$ra_number}{$ra_section}{$ra_zone}</option>";
                            }
                ?>
</select>
```

The current problem is the load time. It currently takes between 11000 and 12000ms to load while the queryload time is 0.020ms in mysql for each query. Is there a way to decrease the loading time in php?

Comment: What have you tried to check which part is responsible for that long duration? Having more than 3000 elements in a single select field looks pretty unusable - maybe you want to use some AJAX related approach that filters the list by a user input?

Comment: Avoid using selects with hundreds or thousands of options.  Use an ajax autocomplete control instead which doesn't require any data at all to load the form page

Comment: Instead of fetching each record separately, use `->fetchAll()` to get all records in one go

Answer (score 0):

Tried `->fetchAll()`. Loading time dropped to 3000ms-4000ms. Ajax autocomplete works perfect.